# Upper-semicontinuous functions and the condition $\limsup_{x\to p} f(x) \le f(p)$

Tags: general-topology, limsup-and-liminf, semicontinuous-functions

When looking at [Wikipedia article about semi-continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) I saw equivalent condition for upper-semicontinuity using limit superior. However, I think that the condition that $X$ is metric is redundant there.

The following is an exact quote from the [current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Semi-continuity&oldid=745106848)
of the Wikipedia article.

> We say that $f$ is *upper semi-continuous* at $x_0$ if for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x) \leq f(x_0) + \epsilon$ for all $x \in U$ when $f(x_0) > -\infty$, and $f(x)$ tends to $-\infty$ as $x$ tends towards $x_0$ when $f(x_0) = -\infty$.
>
> For the particular case of a metric space, this can be expressed as
>   $$\limsup_{x\to x_{0}} f(x)\le f(x_0)$$
>   where lim sup is the limit superior (of the function $f$ at point $x_0$). (For non-metric spaces, an equivalent definition using nets may be stated.)

There is also a corresponding statement about lower semicontinuity and limit inferior.

When I try to prove this characterization or look at proofs elsewhere (for example, [Upper semicontinuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790549/upper-semicontinuous-functions)) I do not see that the assumption that $X$ is metric is needed anywhere. Moreover, sequences or nets do not appear in the statement at all, which makes me even more suspicious.

I understand that metrizability (or some countability axiom) would be needed to get the characterization of upper semicontinuity at the point $p$ in the form $$f(p) \ge \limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} f(x_n)$$ for every sequence $x_n\to p$. (And in this formulation it would make sense to replace sequences by nets.) For example, in this post the characterization using sequences is mentioned for first countable spaces: [Characterization of lower semicontinuous functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711444/characterization-of-lower-semicontinuous-functions)

Am I right that the requirement for $X$ to be metric is not needed there? (I guess that it is possible that the Wikipedia article might be edited as a result of this question. I suppose that Wikipedia editor might be thankful for a reference to a book containing these claims. And so would I.)

Comment: Upper semi-continuity has a role in some theorems in which the domain may not be metrizable. The  general def'n does not require a metric..... If you allow $ -\infty$ among the possible values of $f,$ then the phrase "$ ...f(x)$ tends to $ -\infty$ as $x\to x_0...$" should be : For each  $r\in \mathbb R$ there is a nbhd $U$ of $x_0$ such that $\forall x\in U\;(f(x)<r)$.